# storing sorted list inside ehcache

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I'm new to ehcache and I can't seem to find exactly what I need.

I am using hibernate and have one large table (500k + items) that I need to query fast.

The user requires retrevial of this table in pages, sorted by 4 different attributes. My though was to pre-sort this table and have them stored in 4 different cached lists. The user also has the ability to search through this table.

How can I do this? I would like the data to be pre-fetched and updated from the database automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, actually Hibernate provides all you need out of the box, however the mechanics are a bit complex. First of all you need second level cache (L2). It stores each record as a single item by id. This means you can easily query your objects by id without touching the database.

This alone won't help you and here is where the **query cache** comes into play. Assume you have a query similar to this:

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4
FROM table
ORDER BY c1 ASC
LIMIT 100,20
```

The first time you execute this query, Hibernate will run this against the database, but it will also store all the returned records in L2 and store the result itself (list of ids) in the query cache. Next time you execute the exact same query, Hibernate will find the list of ids in query cache and then fetch each record one after another from L2.

If you use slightly different query, Hibernate will run the SQL and store the result under different key. It uses separate cache for query cache and the key is formed by concatenating query and all parameters.

I am not sure whether Hibernate will store the full result in cache and apply paging in memory or maybe it will store single pages separately, so each query will have as many elements in cache as many distinct pages are possible. If you go this way, it would be great if you could enlighten me.

Also note that any modification done to *any* row in this table via Hibernate will invalidate *all* cached queried involving this table. BTW 500K is not such a big table ;-). If each record occupies 1 KiB, keeping the whole database in memory might be worthwhile.

Comment: I've been playing around with a second level cache through ehcache and it is not providing the performance I need. The query's themselves for each user will be different. The data is also not read-only. It will be updated about 1-2 times a day. I do not want the first hit to be slow, that's why I want to pre-fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

500K records is not a large table by any means.

You're likely to get maximum performance out of this by adequately configuring your database (and underlying OS) so that your table and necessary indexes fit in (and stay in) the cache DB-side.

Hibernate's 2nd level cache + query cache will not be of much help here, especially with mutable data that has to be paginated and sorted in various ways.

Comment: thanks for the info. The table is going to grow to 2-3 million records. Let me mention that the table has 2 relations that are being pulled at the same time. So your saying the max performance from sorting a large collection of items is going to be on db side? Pre-fetch the data and store it in a second level cache is not the way to go?

Comment: @kgibbon Using query cache makes sense for specific queries used on data that rarely changes. At 2-3 million records (paginated + sorted 4 different ways) you're looking at significant overhead (memory and performance-wise) to do that in query cache. And (a part of) that will have to be dropped / re-fetched on every change.

Comment: so what would be my best bet? Im using postgres. Ive got a 8GB machine for the db and we havent tuned it yet. Do you think that is my best bet? Let it up to the db to do the caching and sorting?

Comment: @kgibbon - I would absolutely start on the DB side, yes. With appropriate indexes (assuming we're not talking full text search here) and configuration, PostgreSQL will do a _much_ better job with this then Hibernate's cache under the same memory constraints.

Comment: @kgibbon If you need FTS, look into Hibernate Search / Lucene. Query cache ain't helping you there much either.